# R:BIOMOD error: argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments

Tags: r, modeling, biomod2

I run the following codes using biomod2 package

```
ProLau_models <- 
  BIOMOD_Modeling(
    data = ProLau_data,
    models = c("GLM", "GBM", "RF", "GAM"),
    models.options = ProLau_opt,
    NbRunEval = 2,
    DataSplit = 80,
    VarImport = 3,
    modeling.id = "demo1"
  )
```

I faced the following error.

```
Error in BIOMOD_Modeling(data = ProLau_data, models = c("GLM", "GBM", :
argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments
```

How can I handle this error?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the package or this function, but I get the sense that you are supposed to only use one of "GLM", "GBM", etc.

Answer (score 0):

the package has been updated since this tutorial, so the argument names have changed. try:

```
ProLau_models <- 
  BIOMOD_Modeling(
    bm.format = ProLau_data,
    models = c("GLM", "GBM", "RF", "GAM"),
    bm.options = ProLau_opt,
    nb.rep = 2,
    data.split.perc = 80,
    var.import = 3,
    modeling.id = "demo1"
  )
```